# Why are the regular expressions not working in my php program

Tags: php, regex

i am trying to insert a value in a table but first the data i enter i check the pattern of the data entered using  regular expressions

this is my code ..but it is working can anyone tell me the problem with my code please ?

```
<?php
        extract($_POST);
        $host="localhost"; // Host name
        $username="root"; // Mysql username
        $password="rootpass"; // Mysql password
        $db_name="myshop"; // Database name

        $name=trim($Gname); //trimming the name

        $pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]$/";
        mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server ");
        mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


        if ($name=="")
            echo ("Missing Info");
        else
        {
            if (isset($name))
            {
            if (preg_match($pattern,$name))
                $sql="INSERT INTO ayesha VALUES('$name')";
            else
                echo("wrong syntax");
            }
            else
            {
            echo("missing info");
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: What exactely is not working and what string should regex match?

Comment: Note that your pattern does only match a single character.

Comment: change your pattern to `^[a-zA-Z]+$` , so that it would match one or more letters.

Comment: @FrantišekMaša whtever input is given to $name it must contain letters only ..and the $name input comes from an html form

Comment: @Gumbo i need the input to only have letters ..so the reg exp i have written checks only a single character ?

Comment: @Ashley A character class describes only a single character. If you want to match multiple characters of that class, use a quantifier like `*`, `+`, or `{n,m}`.

Comment: i think you missed a '}' at the last

Answer (score 2):

try this `$pattern="/[a-zA-Z]+/";` instead `$pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]$/";`

```
$pattern="/[a-zA-Z]+/";
//your code
if (!empty($name)) {
    if (preg_match($pattern,$name)) {
        $sql="INSERT INTO ayesha VALUES('$name')";
    } else {
        echo("wrong syntax");
    }
} else {
    echo("missing info");
}
    ?>
```

Comment: While the original pattern was too specific, yours is too broad: you've removed the ^ and $ (start and end of string) anchors, so the string now only has to *include* at least one letter. '-$@!$^53/*a^*86#/' is now a valid input.